# Block UI not working in I.E 8

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-ui, jquery-plugins

i am using block UI .

```
$('#divab div[name=divname]').click(function() { 
         $('#divsecond').block({ 
            message: '<img src="ajax-loader(2).gif" />', 
             css: { 
            top:  ($(window).height() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
            left: ($(window).width() - 400) /2 + 'px', 
            width: '100px',
            border: 'none', 

        backgroundColor: 'transparent', 
        '-webkit-border-radius': '10px', 
        '-moz-border-radius': '10px', 
        opacity: 0.5, 
        color: 'transparent'  
        } 

        }); 
    }); `
```

code is perfectly working in firefox and chrome but not working in i.e 8

Comment: Not working in the sense, Are you able to see the background overlay?